# Toshiba A100 laptop battery wont charge wont run on ac power for more than few minutes..then shut down

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

my Toshiba A100 laptop battery seems to charge when not switched on but pretty much as soon as windows loads it then shows battery dropped down to 7%, then 3% then just shut downs...it then "charges" again  whilst not powered up but am getting the same problem over and over again..any suggestions please it is driving me nuts!

It won't run just on the AC adapter either, so the two things def seem related to me.  When I remove battery and have the AC jack in I get a flicker of blue light on  the power button but it won't stay on or power up, however when battery plugged in and charging I get the yellow/orange charging light,then shows blue fully charged and turn it on and we get same thing again of charge dropping to 7 then 3% then shutdown!

Comment: How old are the laptop, the pattery and the power adapter?

Comment: The laptop is around 5 years old the battery is original, but the power adapter was replaced about 6 months ago but with generic, non toshiba model, same amp and voltage of course though, laptop has always been treated with respect and care etc...Jayne

Comment: I have a 5-year old laptop as well. It has seen some really bad power-related issues. I have replaced the power adapter twice, generic ones. The first one lasted a whole year. The battery... Well... it is 5 years old and holds about 40secs of power. Or less.

Answer (score 2):

[Toshiba forums](http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=54056) appear to suggest that it *could* be a BIOS problem, but also might be a motherboard problem. If the battery is original, there could certainly also be a battery problem, but that forum has a report of somone who got a new battery and a new power adapter and updated the BIOS and still had problems, which were then blamed on the motherboard.

Problems not exactly the same as yours, however.

Your particular symptoms **might** (this is speculaton based on your symptoms) be those of a weak connection on the power input (the old loose power connector problem) in combination with a weak battery. The input power can slowly charge the battery, but the battery doesn't really hold a charge well anymore (being perhaps 6-7 years old, if it's original to a 2006 era laptop.) SO you charge it up while off, it starts up with what little is in the battery, and proceeds to die. Of course, it could also be a bad power adapter rather than a loose connection.

IN any case, you have to ask yourself how much money you want to put into the various things you can try to revive it, rather than put towards a new computer. Once you buy a new power adapter and/or battery, you are probably not going to be able to return them if they don't solve your problem (or I suppose you could try to pick a vendor that would allow you to do so - but those may be rare.)

Comment: Thanks yes I am not sure if it is motherboard as it just seems isolated to the power issues, thanks for your input,and your time and yes you are right it is original battery and I am asking do I just want to throw money at something that may not fix t he issue,instead of putting towards new laptop. I have to say though this laptop h as been exceptionally good, very very reliable and consistent, this is first real issue I have had since buying it new. Although I have replaced the power adapter a while back so its not original Toshiba, maybe its a faulty power adapter,thnx again.Jayne

Answer (score 0):

Get a new power adapter;  they do go bad!  All your symptoms point to it being an adapter problem.  HOWEVER, if the connector for the adapter (in the laptop) is loose, then it's more likely that the solder joint(s) are breaking & so the laptop isn't charging as it should.

Comment: Thanks for your time and comment I think you maybe right,i just remembered I replaced the power adapter a while back with a generic one,I will also try change my advanced power settings for the battery so that it doesn't auto shut down at "low" or "critical" levels just to see if it actually then will charge up if it does i will then know it is the battery that needs replacing and/or the power adapter..as I can access all my software and files internet etc for the short time it runs I don;t thin k it is anything tooo serious, it runs,perfectly, just not for long! Thanks again - Jayne

Answer (score 0):

To find more detailed information about the current state of your battery, you can try using a [Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) (or [USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#live-usb)) of a Linux distro. Click the battery icon in the upper bar to display battery information.

In the screenshot below you can see the information being displayed in Ubuntu. Compare the "Energy (design)" with the "energy when full" to see if it has lost its capacity.

[image]